# How Coveo reads indexes?

Tags: content-search, coveo

We are using Coveo on perm 4.0 edition with Sitecore 8.1 update 3. 
We have CM and CD configured to use the Coveo indexes.

When I query the results on CM and on CD it uses different indexes

[image]

So how do I tell Coveo to use particular index which I know has proper documents?

For testing purposes I want Coveo to use only CD indexes for CM and CD both.

I tried searching for the index names used in screenshot in all Coveo configs but could not find anything.

Any inputs here?

Comment: When you say "how do i tell coveo to use particular index which i know have proper documents", do you mean to ask how you tell Sitecore what indexes to use? And I assume you mean the front end of the site and not the authoring environment?

Comment: Yes sorry if it's not clear but that's what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Coveo for Sitecore, the default filters only include the documents that are in your current index, based on the name.

The name of the index is created using the following logic:

`(INDEX_NAME) - ((INSTANCE_NAME) OR (FARM_NAME))` OR `(SOURCE_NAME)`.

So if you want both Sitecore instances to query the same index, the recommended way is to set the same `farmName` tag in both configurations, as specified in the [Coveo for Sitecore Scaling Guide](https://developers.coveo.com/x/3oAkAg).

Is is configurable in the **Control Panel** > **Coveo Search** > **Configuration**, and select **Configure** under the **Farm Name** section.